# Pdf is not previewable in Electron-Vue Desktop Application

Tags: vue.js, electron, jspdf, pdf-viewer

I have used *`electron-vue`* to create desktop application. I was trying to preview a pdf in my application. I have tried **`JsPdf, vue-pdf, iframe etc`**. But nothing has worked.

I am using **`Vue 2.5.16`** version.
I can download the pdf using *`jspdf`* but can't preview it. While importing *`vue-pdf`* I got unrecognized token error.

Anyone knows any alternative solution?
Any kind of help is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

electron-vue is very outdated.
it uses electron 2.0.4, now we have electron 9.1.0.
you can read it in the dependencys [here](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue/blob/master/template/package.json).
And from a personal project i know that the pdf bug has fixed in 9.0.
Here you find the [Github Issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/22286)

So at least try to update the dependencys